# How to make a custom wide sub menu in a WordPress site

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to replicate the submenu as shown in the picture in my wordpress all i know is to drag and drog the sub-menu in to the menu to make it sub but i can't find a way to have a wide custom submenu in my wordpress site .
Like in this example the sub-menu is below when i hover the mouse over shop All.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of these menues based on the CSS-Framework they're using. Most common one is Bootstrap.

If you just looking for a plugin to do this, choose one of these:
[Top 10 Mega Menues](https://www.sourcewp.com/wordpress-mega-menu-plugins/)

Or if you just want to split one submenu via CSS: [Look at this](http://www.prowebdesign.ro/wordpress-sub-menu-items-split-in-2-columns-the-easy-way/)

But if you want really to customize and create such a menu by yourself I would suggest to:

- Look into the 'Mega Menu plugins' and look how they are working.
- Or add and style a custom wide column div-container to your theme. Hide it then with display:none and move the content to your target-menu via jQuery/Javascript.